# Efficiently create millions of object in Django ORM?

Tags: django, performance, postgresql, parsing, csv

I'm working on a program where I need to efficiently parse and import about 3 millions of objects into a database, using Django + PostgreSQL. I've got a .csv file which stores the information for 2 related models (think of a `Author-Book` [1:n] like relation).

So far I'm splitting the file in 1000 lines and process them in a method with the `@transaction.atomic` decorator. Inside that method I check with a `author = Author.objects.filter(pk=author_pk).first()`if an author has been created before and if so skip the parsing of the author-related part of the line, same goes for books.

Yet the program will still take 3 hours to complete... Any hint how I could speed up things?

Thank you :)

Comment: did you try to insert objects directly to the database?

Comment: Have you thought about starting multiple celery tasks?

Comment: can be done in a few minutes if you leave out the frontend crap.

Comment: Forego the ORM, and create insert/update statements directly. This extreme case of batch processing warrants it. The joys of ORMs are plenty, but not universal - you hit one of the sour spots here.

Comment: @ÇağatayBarın: how would you go about that? Would you directly write plain sql?

Comment: @ilse2005: unfortunately it's a single-core processor so I guess multi-threading won't lead to big performance increase?

Comment: @wildplasser: I'm leaving out the frontend stuff, just operating via a manage.py command ;)

Comment: @deets: so you would also recommend generating a SQL that can be executed?

Comment: Since you have your csv files, you can parse your csv file and create a sql insert code with it with any programming language you're comfortable with.

Comment: @ÇağatayBarın: thank you :) I'll give it a shot!

Comment: Good luck with that. I can help you if you stuck.